# In Windows 10, how can I move giant AppData folder to another drive?

Tags: windows-10, android-studio

People seem to think it's risky to do this.

But I'm trying to work with Android Studio which is **enormous**.

It's made my AppData folder literally 30 Gb with all the images of virtual machines and different versions of the libraries in the SDK.

I installed Android Studio itself on another drive, but it's still putting all its junk in AppData. My C drive is now full, and the only way I can imagine solving this problem without breaking Android Studio is if I can move AppData itself behind a symlink.

I saw instructions here : https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-tip-move-your-default-data-folders-to-a-different-drive/

But it suggests if I click on properties on the folder I'll find a move option. There's nothing like this on the properties pop up.

So. Is it possible? If so, how?

Is it dangerous / a bad idea? If so, what can I do about Android Studio which seems determined to use AppData rather than the directory where I put it.

Comment: Just to add: You can just move the AndroidSDK into a different location. It is a lot easier (and probably better option) than moving the whole AppData due to 1 software eating up space. Just move the AndroidSDK folder elsewhere and make sure your Android Studio points to the new location.

Comment: That's what I tried to do. But it seemed to reset itself to pointing back to AppData.